# Get each char (with shape) of font from UIFont or .ttf file

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, fonts

I have not exact idea for it is possible or not and also I did try to find solution for my question but did't get success, that's why I am asking here and hope that I will get solution.

I am developing one drawing related app in which I want to get shape of each font that provided by `.ttf` file or `UIFont`.

**For Ex.**

If I have **UIFont/.ttf file** such like `"OpenSans-Italic"` then how can get each "char" with it's shape ***(here "Italic" shape)*** of `"OpenSans"` font?
And I want to this in `Char or NSString.`

> *=> @[ @"a", @"b", @"c", @"d",..@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D",.....@"1", @"2", @"3"....]; // This is char array only for understanding purpose.*

Please suggest me, how can I get this?

Comment: Do you want each character as an [attributed string](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/) or as an image?

Comment: @KennethBruno Not image I want each char as string.

Comment: Maybe this is help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6991793/2754158 looks like the code there gets font character set.

Comment: Instead of `UIFont` or `CGFont`, you should probably go for `CTFont`. Core Text is the only framework that will let you get the shape (path) of a glyph (note that a font doesn't represent characters, it represents glyphs. A character can be composed from multiple glyphs, e.g. characters with diacritics, and character sequences can be represented with one glyph, e.g. ligatures).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it, borrowing from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33917661/887210) post. It iterates through all the possible characters in a [`NSCharacterSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/) and finds those that are valid. Right now it's using [`.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/URLPathAllowedCharacterSet) but it could use others.

```
import UIKit

var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
if let font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Italic", size: 12) {
  let charset = NSCharacterSet.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet()
  for var plane : UInt32 in 0...16 where charset.hasMemberInPlane(UInt8(plane)) {
    let planeRange = (plane << 16)..<((plane+1) << 16)
    for characterValue in planeRange where charset.longCharacterIsMember(characterValue) {
      let character = String(UnicodeScalar(CFSwapInt32HostToLittle(characterValue)))
      attributedString.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string:character, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:font]))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for give answer, can you please convert this code in Objective-C ?

Comment: @iPatel Your question lists Swift as the language that you are using. If you go to the link I posted there is similar Objective-C code in one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Is it work if available glyphs are listed in code? If it works, everything seems easy.

I mean add some build phase to parse font file and generate some code including all available chars. I have created a project that provided similar idea [IconFont](https://github.com/JohnWong/IconFont/tree/develop/). This project provide UIImage from font file. In develop branch, I add a build phase to parse ttf font file using project [PyTTF](https://github.com/JohnWong/PyTTF) and add code to [TBCityIcon.m](https://github.com/JohnWong/IconFont/blob/develop/Example/Classes/TBCityIcon.m). It is easy to modify the python script to generate code of a NSArray that contains all available chars.